# ASP .NET MouseMove Event

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio

If I have a .aspx file where the Page's language property is set to C#, how do I set up an onmousemove event? I put one in the html, but I get a javascript error. I can't include a javascript because I already set the language to C#.

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server" onmousemove="Mouse_Move">
```

Im mising something with how this is supposed to work.

Comment: Even if you set the page's language to C#, that only applies to C# code that is within a script tag that has the `runat="server"` attribute. Otherwise it'll just run like normal JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would not send a mouse move event back to the server where your C# code resides as it would be constantly firing.

You are free to use JavaScript on an asp.net page regardless of what server side language you choose to use.  Depending on what you're trying to to accomplish you may also be able to use CSS to accomplish the same effect.

Comment: Ok, it may have been because in my script declaration I was setting the language and should have just been setting the type to "text/javascript"

Comment: Yeah that was it. I just set the "type" and the "src" with the <script> tag and was able to run everything fine. Thank you.